# The best place to store custom interfaces in ZF2

Tags: php, oop, interface, zend-framework2

Where is the best place to store **custom interfaces** in **Zend Framework 2**?
For example interface for "User" entity

Comment: This question is out of scope for SO, you should read the [guide on what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However as ZF2 seem to place their interfaces in the same folders as where they're typically used, it's probably worth following suit. See the [paginator source](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-paginator/tree/master/src) as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually best place for user entity would be User module's Entity directory (User\Entity\UserInterface). But if you build different architecture than module driven best place will be Application modules directory. IMHO

Comment: But i would recommend you Modules driven architecture it's easier to maintain and more readable than your own